# Why does rsync sometimes fail to overwrite my local files?

Tags: rsync

I have a script called `copy-site` which I use to copy a site from the production server to my local machine. `copy-site example.net/httpdocs/ example.local/httpdocs/` will do a dry run rsync; adding a third parameter of `true` does the copy for real.

Sometimes, the local files have been edited. In this case, I want `rsync` to throw away my local edits, overwriting them with what's on the server. However, often it does not do this. Nor does it show anything relevant in an error log. I tried redirecting stderr to a log file, but it's usually empty or contains warnings about directories it cannot access on the remote server; it says nothing about not overwriting certain files. And certainly it can access those files: if I delete the local copies, and then run it again, it creates them fine, as a perfect copy of what they are on the server.

I added the `-I` flag today, but it made no discernible difference.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$3" = true ]
then
    echo "real rsync";
    echo "deleting files";
    find $2 -type f -name ".*" -delete;
    echo "rsync running now";
    rsync -avziI --verbose --exclude-from /home/trig/copy-site-exclude -e 'ssh -p 2201' trig@server.example.net:/var/www/vhosts/$1 $2 --append-verify --delete;
    notify-send -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "copy site" "rsync complete";
    echo "setting permissions";
    chmod -R 0777 $2;
    notify-send -i terminal "copy site" "full permissions granted";
else
    echo "dry run rsync";
    rsync -avziI --verbose --exclude-from /home/trig/copy-site-exclude -e 'ssh -p 2201' trig@server.example.net:/var/www/vhosts/$1 $2 --append-verify --delete --dry-run;
    notify-send -i terminal "copy site" "dry run complete";
fi
```

`copy-site-exclude` is merely a list of image thumbnails (identified as beginning with dots), which I don't care to transfer as they can be regenerated locally.

```
custom/public/images/.*.jpg
custom/public/images/.*.png
custom/public/images/.*.gif
custom/public/images/.*.jpeg
```

What flags do I need to pass to rsync to make it discard all local changes, so that my local folder is a perfect reflection of the source folder on the server?

Local OS: Ubuntu.
Server OS: CentOS.

Comment: If you run `copy-site example.net/httpdocs example.local/httpdocs` then you will run `rsync -avziI --verbose --exclude-from /home/trig/copy-site-exclude -e 'ssh -p 2201' trig@server.example.net:/var/www/vhosts/example.net/httpdocs example.local/httpdocs --append-verify --delete` and end up with `example.local/httpdocs/httpdocs/.[your files here]`. Add trailing slashes to both arguments to get what I expect is the required behaviour (i.e. no double `httpdocs` directories).

Comment: @wurtel. Oops. But that's not the issue. The issue is that sometimes a file will be edited locally, and should be overwritten back to the way it was, but is not; or edited on the server, which should overwrite the local, but doesn't. Usually small text/PHP files, only ~6 lines long.

Comment: Try adding the -c (--checksum) argument: skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size

Comment: @parkamark. Running that now, and (as I should have expected) it takes far longer. Is it actually downloading each file to calculate the checksum?

Comment: It's looking at the file contents, not just the mod-time and size, yes. I think I encountered this same issue with my backups and adding this flag fixed things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simplifying the command (removing the `-z` and `--append-verify` flags) seems to have done the trick. However, I would still like to know what is actually happening here. From my reading, those flags *shouldn’t* have the effect of silently failing to overwrite (or to delete) some local files.

The line is now

```
rsync -avi --verbose --exclude-from /home/trig/copy-site-exclude -e 'ssh -p 2201' trig@server.example.net:/var/www/vhosts/$1 $2 --delete;
```

I’m not sure whether this is an answer (I’ve fixed my immediate problem) or a new question (why did this happen?). I’ll leave it here, anyway.